# Cant find /data/db folder (MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm unable to find my ~/data/db folder that i created for MongoDB.

I created it with "sudo mkdir - p /data/db" in my root folder. I am unsure of what the "sudo" command does as it seems the folder is hidden in some way. If i navigate to the root folder it does not contain a /data/db folder. Altho my MongoDB works and i can save things to the DB.

I've tried "sudo ls" in root with no result.

To get my mongoDB going i have to do:
    "sudo ./mongod"
    "sudo ./mongo"

in my mongodb/bin folder.

If i don't type sudo random errors (which i can insert here if needed) appears.

TLDR: Seems like my ~/data/db is under some privacy setting. Cant find it in the finder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sudo` means you're creating the folder as the `root` user, which means that it'll be created with `root`'s default permissions - typically, not enough for other users to work with it.

I'm also confused as to what you're really trying to achieve. Are you trying to create a `/data/db` folder in your home directory (`mkdir -p ~/data/db`) or in the root directory (`sudo mkdir -p /data/db`)? You mention both as if they were equivalent, but they really are not. Assuming your user name is `bangalter`, the former will be in `/home/bangalter/data/db` and the later in `/data/db`. Obviously, if you're sudoing to run mongodb, you're executing it as the `root` user whose home is neither `/` nor `/home/bangalter`, but `/home/root`.

In short: you're not having issues with mongodb but suffering from a lack of familiarity with unix user management / directory structure. This is easily remedied, however, as there are literally thousands of articles, books and tutorials on those.

Comment: That explained a whole lot that i did not know. Thanks. Is there any way for me to access the files of the root-user in Finder? I'm interested in taking a look at the actual files mongoDB saves. How would i solve the problem of having to use "sudo" on everything? Can i make the data/db folder just be a folder of my own user and not the root-user?

Comment: Well, the simplest solution for your particular use case would probably be for you to specify where you want mongodb to store its data files through its `--dbpath PATH` argument - say, `mongod --dbpath ~/data/db`, for example.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Making big progress with my understanding here. I started mongodb with the ~/data/db path and was able to start the shell with "sudo ./mongo" and insert some files and see them pop up in finder. One last question: Why did u have to run the shell with sudo but not mongoD?

Comment: The only explanation I can think of is that the shell doesn't have executable permissions for anyone but `root`. Use `which mongo` to see where your binary is located, `ls -l /path/to/mongo` to view the permissions and then change them with `chmod`.